# Sum of $\frac{9}{5^2\cdot 2 \cdot 1}+\frac{13}{5^3 \cdot 3 \cdot 2}+\frac{17}{5^4 \cdot 4 \cdot 3}+\ldots \text{to} \hspace{0.1 cm} \infty $

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the sum of the series

$$\frac{9}{5^2\cdot 2 \cdot 1}+\frac{13}{5^3 \cdot 3 \cdot 2}+\frac{17}{5^4 \cdot 4 \cdot 3}+\ldots \text{to}  \hspace{0.1 cm} \infty $$

I see that $r_{th}$ term is $\frac{5+4r}{5^{r+1} \cdot r \cdot(r+1)}$ and I am look to find sum of $n$ terms and then put $n \to \infty$ .

Could someone provide me insight to find some of $n$ terms or any other better approach?

Comment: By $5^{r+1}.r.(r+1)$ do you mean $5^{r+1}\cdot r \cdot (r+1)$?

Comment: @ÁngelMarioGallegos What would it be too? :o

Comment: @Shadock. The second dot could be a decimal point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$\frac{5+4r}{5^{r+1} r(r+1)} = \frac{5(1+r)-r}{5^{r+1}r(r+1)} = \frac{1}{ 5^{r} r}-\frac{1}{5^{r+1}(r+1)}$$
hence the series is telescopic:
$$ \sum_{r\geq 1}\frac{5+4r}{5^{r+1} r(r+1)} = \frac{1}{5^1\cdot 1}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{5}}$$
and:
$$ \sum_{r=1}^{R}\frac{5+4r}{5^{r+1} r(r+1)} = \frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{5^{R+1}(R+1)}.$$

Comment: Very nice solution.